# Promise return Array Scope not updated

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i display the data like

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in getAllEngagementItems | filter:searchText">
    <td>{{item.wafId}}</td>
    <td>{{item.engagementProjectName}}</td>
    <td>{{item.engagementLibraryStatus}}</td>
</tr>
```

In controller

```
app.controller("EngagementController", function ($scope, WAFDatafactory) {
    $scope.getAllEngagementItems = myfunction();

    function myfunction() {

        var output;
        var items = WAFDatafactory.getAllEngagementItems();

        items.$promise.then(function (results) {
            $scope.$emit('UpdateEngagementCount', results.length);
            output = results;
            console.log("Output detais :" + output);
        }
        , function (error) {
            alert("Failed to Retrive data from server" + error);
            console.log("Error detais :" + error);
        });

        return output;
    }

});
```

datafactory

```
factory.getAllEngagementItems = function () {
    var allEngagementItems = $resource("/api/data/GetEngagementData/").query();
    return allEngagementItems;
}
```

output :

Output detais :[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]....

**my scope.getAllEngagementItems  does not get updated and view does not get list items.**

Comment: I believe you need to provide some kind of formatting for your array so that it is converted to a string. For example, `JSON.stringify(output)`

Comment: Thanks, that worked but, Why my UI is not getting list.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see that `output` is necessary. You can just return a promise.

```
app.controller("EngagementController", function ($scope, WAFDatafactory) {
    $scope.getAllEngagementItems = myfunction();

    function myfunction() {

        var items = WAFDatafactory.getAllEngagementItems();

        items.$promise.then(function (results) {
            $scope.$emit('UpdateEngagementCount', results.length);
            console.log("Output detais :" + results);
        }
        , function (error) {
            alert("Failed to Retrive data from server" + error);
            console.log("Error detais :" + error);
        });

        return items;
    }

});
```

The reason that your code didn't work was:

When `myFunction()` was run, `WAFDatafactory.getAllEngagementItems()` returned a promise, but the actual query was run async. So the value of `output` would be `undefined` when you returned it. However, `undefined` is a primitive value instead of an object. So when you updated `output` later on, it would never effect the real value of `$scope.getAllEngagementItems` .

Comment: @srieen The reason that your code didn't work was, when `myFunction()` was run, the query was run async, the value of `output` would be `undefined` when you returned it. However, `undefined` is a primitive value instead of an object. So when you updated `output` later on, it would never effect the real value of `$scope.getAllEngagementItems` .

Comment: Thanks Tong ! It make scene.